# Bluetooth LE and Fedora

Tags: fedora, bluetooth, fedora-38

I have an Dell inspiron 5406 with Feodra 38. I would like to retrieve data from devices using BLE.

However, using bluetoothctl I can't saw them.
I'm sure their are one since I can see them with the Bluetooth of my phone.

Basically I tried this setting:

```sh
> bluetoothctl
# menu scan
# transport le
# back
# scan on
```

I don't see the device I'm looking for. If I remove the transport filter, I see my phone.

1/ How to know if the bluetoothe of my computer support the BLE? (I taped the command `btmgmt info` giving me the result `supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr le advertising secure-conn debug-keys privacy configuration static-addr phy-configuration wide-band-speech`. LE appears, but I'm not sure it is a related to hardware or to btmgmt).

2/ What could I do to see the devices ?